# python import random issue - AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

im using python3 and i get this errors:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'

passwordGen =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(12, 20)))
NameError: name 'randint' is not defined
```

This is my code:

```
import random
from random import uniform, random, choice, sample, randint
somelist = ["temp1"]
randomList = random.choice(somelist)
```

And:

```
characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
passwordGen =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(12, 20)))
```

I know i have only one item in the list, most of the time i have more then 1 
in this specific code i have one

I tried to import random only, and then i added from random, every time i get a different error
when i change my imports.

If i do it in my python3 :

```
>>> a = ["temp1"]
>>> import random
>>> b = random.choice(a)
>>> b
'temp1'
```

So what is the issue ?

Comment: When you use *random* in your code, which one do you think it is: `import random` or `from random import uniform, random, ...`?

Comment: I now tried only `from random import random, choice, randint
` and same error: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'`

Comment: Then use simply *choice*.

Comment: what do you mean ? what to import  ? i also need the randint for the seconde code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `import random` this binds the name "random" to the built-in module `random` (which contains a `choice` function). However on the next line you do:

```
from random import uniform, random, choice, sample, randint
```

Here the `from random import random` *rebinds* the name "random" to the function `random.random` which you just imported. Hence the subsequent `random.choice` resolves "random" to that function and not the module. Instead you can directly use `choice` as you did later.

Comment: I now tried only `from random import random, choice, randint` and got the error  `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'`

Comment: @BatchenRegev For the same reasons as before. `from X import Y` binds the name "Y" to the object `X.Y`. Hence in your case "random" is bound to `random.random`; this function does not have an attribute `choice` (as the error indicates). The *module* `random` contains a `choice` function, so you need to *either* `import random` and then `random.choice` *or* `from random import random, choice, randint` and then just `choice`.

Comment: what do you mean and then import choice ? im sorry but i dont get it, can you write me how to import ? like this ? : `import random
from random import choice
`   or `import random import random.choice`

Comment: @BatchenRegev You have two options. (1) `import random` and then access any function through the name "random"; for example `random.choice(...), random.randint(...), random.random(...)`. (2) `from random import choice, randint, random` and then access any function directly by its imported name; for example `choice(...), randint(...), random(...)`. Notably the last occurrence of `random` refers to the *function* not the *module*. You could also mix the two options unless you do `from random import ..., random` since this shadows the previous `import random`.

Comment: Thank you now i got it, anyway i used this in the end :`import random
from random import choice, randint
`

Comment: @BatchenRegev As I mentioned, as long as you don't shadow the `import random` with another `from random import random` it's okay to mix the two import options. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.